# Is it possible to fetch NRU value per document in Couchbase client SDKs?

Tags: couchbase

As pointed out in the documentation, Couchbase ejects documents from memory according to its NRU value : [Couchbase - Not Recently Used (NRU) Items](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/5.0/architecture/db-engine-architecture.html#not-recently-used-nru-items)

I wonder if it is possible to get NRU value of the document somehow (API,etc)?

Comment: Can you explain what would be the use case for that?

Comment: I would like to know which documents are fetched from disk (which has high NRU values), so that I can delete them, is there any other way possible for this?

Comment: You can simply use Ephemeral buckets in Couchbase, https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/learn/buckets-memory-and-storage/buckets.html